# Footer nav list vertical space way too much

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do four columns in my footer of a list of  anchor tags using the bootstrap 4.4 nav classes. I have the columns done just fine but the vertical padding top and bottom between each nav item is much too great. I have tried with no luck to fix this. You can see from the attached image how much space is there. It is a lot and all four footer columns look just like this one. Does someone know the answer to this issue?

```html
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted" style="background-color: darkblue" >
        <div class="container" style="background-color: darkblue">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm" style="background-color: darkblue">
                    <h4 style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">Company</h4>
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item p-0">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Terms">Terms of Use</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                ... Three other columns just like above
          </div>
       </div>
   </footer>
```

[image: footer column]

Comment: bootstrap navs only add `.5rem 1rem` padding. So it likely some custom styles that are causing this. Inspect the element and see where the extra padding/margin/line-height might be coming from.

Comment: WizardCoder thank you so much... The Visual Studio Razor pages template had added a .footer in the site.css with a line-height: 60px. Changed 60px to 10px and everything closed up as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the padding on nav-link

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Bootstrap isn't properly linked. I loaded your snippet into a new HTML file with this in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I got a much tighter layout: 
[my attempt loaded in FF Dev 73](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwlop.png)

I suspect this means you're linking the wrong version of Bootstrap.css.